# How to make this R code more elegant?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm solving a R exercise but I think I could do this code more elegant or simple. I'm working with diamonds dataset from ggplot2. I have to delete outliers from numeric variables, and a outlier is for me a row for which any numeric variable is above or below of median +/- 3 times MAD (Median Absolute Deviation). My actual code is very manual:

```
library(dplyr)

filter(numeric.vars, 
    carat > median(carat) - 3 * mad(carat),
    carat < median(carat) + 3 * mad(carat),
    depth > median(depth) - 3 * mad(depth),
    depth < median(depth) + 3 * mad(depth),
    table > median(table) - 3 * mad(table),
    table < median(table) + 3 * mad(table),
    price > median(price) -3 * mad(price),
    price < median(price) +3 * mad(price),
    x > median(x) - 3 * mad(x),
    x < median(x) + 3 * mad(x),
    y > median(y) - 3 * mad(y),
    y < median(y) + 3 * mad(y),
    z > median(z) - 3 * mad(z),
    z < median(z) + 3 * mad(z)) -> clean
```

Should I do something like `apply(numeric.vars,1, myCustomFunction)` to apply the condition over each row? Although by rows, I don't know which column a data belongs to.

Comment: all three answers are roughly the same speed as long as you use `function(x) abs((x - median(x)) / mad(x)) < 3` instead of two separate logic checks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We create a logical index of `numeric` columns ('numeric.vars'), loop through those columns of the dataset, apply the condition with `median` and `mad`, and check whether all the variables comply with the condition for each row (using `Reduce` and `&`) to create a logical `vector` ('i1') which we used to subset the rows of 'diamonds' dataset.

```
numeric.vars <- sapply(diamonds, is.numeric)
i1 <-  Reduce(`&`, lapply(diamonds[numeric.vars], function(v) 
        (v > median(v) - 3* mad(v)) & (v < median(v) + 3 * mad(v))) )
SubDiam <- diamonds[i1,]
nrow(SubDiam)
#[1] 44736
```

Based on the OP's code

```
nrow(clean)
#[1] 44736
```

Comment: I like your answer. A good debate has been created :) Thanks to all!

Answer (score 5):

The `assertr` package contains a `within_n_mads` function, which is helpful. However, to use it outside of its usual framework, a little work is needed. `within_n_mads(3)` returns a function that will create a new function when passed a vector. *That* function tests individual values.

Thus, with a little `purrr` (hybridize with `dplyr` if you like),

```
library(purrr)
library(assertr)

diamonds %>% keep(is.numeric) %>%    # Subset to numeric columns
    # Change all values to logical of whether it is within 3 mads
    dmap(~within_n_mads(3)(.x)(.x)) %>% 
    # Filter diamonds to rows where all columns of . are TRUE
    reduce(`&`) %>% diamonds[., ]

## # A tibble: 44,736 × 10
##    carat       cut color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
##    <dbl>     <ord> <ord>   <ord> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
## 1   0.23     Ideal     E     SI2  61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43
## 2   0.21   Premium     E     SI1  59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31
## 3   0.29   Premium     I     VS2  62.4    58   334  4.20  4.23  2.63
## 4   0.31      Good     J     SI2  63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75
## 5   0.24 Very Good     J    VVS2  62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48
## 6   0.24 Very Good     I    VVS1  62.3    57   336  3.95  3.98  2.47
## 7   0.26 Very Good     H     SI1  61.9    55   337  4.07  4.11  2.53
## 8   0.23 Very Good     H     VS1  59.4    61   338  4.00  4.05  2.39
## 9   0.30      Good     J     SI1  64.0    55   339  4.25  4.28  2.73
## 10  0.23     Ideal     J     VS1  62.8    56   340  3.93  3.90  2.46
## # ... with 44,726 more rows
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the `data.table` package the first function will return a table showing the result for each value.  The second function will check if all values pass the filter.

```
dt <- as.data.table(diamonds)
dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) abs((x-median(x))/mad(x))<3), .SDcols=sapply(dt, is.numeric)]
index <- dt[, Reduce("+", lapply(.SD, function(x) abs((x-median(x))/mad(x))<3))==length(.SD), .SDcols=sapply(dt, is.numeric)]
dt[index, .N]
```

to display all diamonds that meet the filter

```
dt[index]
```

**simplified logic check**

With a small data set the time difference will likely be irrelevant, but I wanted to highlight that using the following function will be almost twice as fast the other two answers

```
function(x) abs((x - median(x)) / mad(x)) < 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr` package we apply the `in_range` function below that returns `True` if your condition applies on a each column on its own, then `rowwise()` and `Reduce('&')` to apply it on the row as a whole.
And `numeric.vars` is renamed to `df` for simplicity.

```
in_range <- function(x) {
  (x > median(x) - (3*mad(x))) & (x < median(x) + (3*mad(x)))
}

df <- diamonds[sapply(diamonds, is.numeric)]

clean <- df[df %>% mutate_each(funs=funs(in_range)) %>% rowwise() %>% Reduce('&',.),]

nrow(clean)  # 44736
```

Or the one-liner suggested by @alistaire

```
diamonds %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>% mutate_all(funs((. > (median(.) - 3 * mad(.))) & (. < (median(.) + 3 * mad(.))))) %>% { filter(diamonds, Reduce(`&`, .)) }
```

Comment: your comments said you renamed `numeric.vars` to `df` which creates an error.  Using `diamonds[numeric.vars] %>% mutate_each(funs=funs(in_range)) %>% rowwise() %>% Reduce('&',.)` works for me.

Comment: @manotheshark - `df <- diamonds[sapply(diamonds, is.numeric)]` I'll update the answer to make it clear. Which in your case would be `df <- diamonds[numeric.vars]`. Thank you!

Comment: You could write it entirely in `dplyr` like so: `diamonds %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>% mutate_all(funs((. > (median(.) - 3 * mad(.))) & (. < (median(.) + 3 * mad(.))))) %>% { filter(diamonds, Reduce(\`&\`, .)) }`

Comment: Thanks @alistaire. I'll definitely use the curly braces and `select_if` more in the future.

Comment: They can be handy. `magrittr` has a couple other tricks up its sleeve as well, but if you really want to see how far a pipe can go, check out [`pipeR`](https://renkun.me/pipeR-tutorial/).